# I want to display the total number of messages in my device

Tags: java, android

Is there a way of determining the number of total messages in our device.

I've tried the following for finding the number of calls:

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
                Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);

                count= c.getCount();

                Log.i("TAG",Integer.toString(count));
```

But I'm not able to view any number when i tried this similar to messages in my logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get all  Messages

```
public List<String> getSMS(){
List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  
}

if (cur != null) {
    cur.close();
}
return sms;
}
```

Just Call the method and you will receive an ArrayList of all messages

Comment: is there any permissions required for this? thanks i got this

Comment: yes READ SMS. just add this line to your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: at the end i wrote:               Log.i("TAG",Integer.toString(sms.size()));
to get the size of the list. But I'm not able to get any value in my logcat. any idea?

Comment: which device you running ??i mean version of device

Comment: my device runs android N

Comment: then u have to request for runtime permission or give if manually from appinfo activity

Answer (score 0):

Get List of Messages in Inbox Like Below:

First Add Permission in Manifest.xml to read sms:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

 public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox()
{
    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList();

    //Read Draft message only by "content://sms/draft"
    //Read Sent message only by "content://sms/sent"

    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while  (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
           String address = cursor.getString(1);
           String body = cursor.getString(3);

           sms.add(body);
    }
    return sms;

}
```

And You can get SMS count by `sms.size();`

Comment: i'm not able to get any value in my logcat by writing the following after your code:            Log.i("TAG",Integer.toString(sms.size()));

Comment: Get No of sms as string like this  Log.d(TAG, "onClick: NO_OF_SMS= "+String.valueOf(fetchInbox().size()));

Comment: this shows the following error:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: initialize arraylist ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList(); like this